# Получение данных с com-порта

Tags: c#

Работаю с com-портом. Входящие данные на com-порт получаю так:

```
public static void ScanerDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
}
```

Полученное значение indata:

```
?\u0002\u0006C\t\0\087?\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0mU
```

Дальнейшие действия:

```
    byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(indata);
    string hexString = Encoding.Default.GetString(ba);
```

Получаем:

```
"3F-02-06-43-09-00-00-38-37-3F-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-6D-55"
```

Если посмотреть что приходит на com-порт бесплатной программой ComRead, то значение будет вот таким:

```
AA 02 06 43 09 00 00 38 37 86 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6D 55
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно получить значение как в ComRead?

Comment: это разве не c#? при чем тут с++?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Ошибся. c#

Comment: Попробуйте сменить кодировку (вместо Default) во время получения результата. Для примера:  ASCIIEncoding, UTF8Encoding, UnicodeEncoding, UTF32Encoding

Comment: Прошу прощения, в моем случае это вот тут -  byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(indata)

Comment: Encoding здесь вообще не должно быть. Преобразовывать непонятный мусор в другую кодировку только для получения HEX абсолютно бессмысленно. Работайте с отдельными байтами и форматируйте их в HEX: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-hexadecimal-x-format-specifier

Comment: Добрый день!
Задача решилась путем внесения изменений:

byte[] ba = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
sp.Read(ba, 0, ba.Length);

Может кому то пригодится.